# putting the event listener in different class ..?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

let's say that i have this button which is called "Click_Here" and i added an event listener to it in some class file in order for it to run the event handler in a different one ..
so it will be like this

classfile1.as

```
Click_Here.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK , buttonClicked ) ;
```

classfile2.as

```
public function buttonClicked (e:MouseEvent){ trace ("hello");}
```

is that possible .. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Consider the class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public function MyClass()
    {
    }

    public static function staticListener(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("static");
    }

    public function instanceListener(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("instance");
    }
}
```

Now do this:

```
Click_Here.addEventListner(ouseEvent.CLICK , MyClass.staticListener);
```

Or:

```
var obj:MyClass = new MyClass();
Click_Here.addEventListner(ouseEvent.CLICK , obj.instanceListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's possible:

```
Click_Here.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK , instanceOfClass2.buttonClicked ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer

o'reilly essential actionscript 3.0. book.

That will give you clear clarity.